# Changing symlink "python" crashes python applications

Tags: 16.04, python3, symbolic-link

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. and I have installed python3.5 and python3.8
There is a symlink `/usr/bin/python3` which points to `/usr/bin/python3.5`

Now after installing *python3.8*, I wanted the link `python3` to point to `python3.8` so I changed the symlink. But the consequences are terrible. Python applications such as `update-manager` or `zim` give following error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized
module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib
/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

So I changed it back, but is there any possibility to make python3.8 the default `python3`?

Comment: Not yet. A future release of Ubuntu will use Py3.8, and upgrading to that release of Ubuntu will accomplish what you seek. Older releases of Ubuntu feature older software. While you wait, DO NOT change the `python3` symlink - as you discovered, doing so breaks your system.

Comment: @user535733 thanks for information. So I know there is nothing to do about it. And yes, I can wait to the new Ubuntu release with python3.8 :) — Please, write your commentary as answer, it is good enough to get accepted.